# How to make 2 raster to be the same extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

I got two raster files of rice suitability area and land use. Two layers have the same cell size (400x400 meters). However, rice suitability layer extent is (234,298) column and row, while extent of land use layer is (229,288). It caused a big trouble when I run allocation model. I would like to make extent of suitability layer to be the same with land use layer.

I have tried to use data management> raster> raster processing> clip and selected environment> processing extent> select extent same as layer land use and/or snap raster to "land use" layer. Unfortunately, the extent of rice suitability layer is the same.

How can I fix this problem with ArcGIS?

Comment: How about using *land use* layer as a mask? In `Geoprocessing | Environments | Raster Analysis` there is an option to select a layer as Mask. Then subsequent outputs will be masked by the extent of *land use*. (Cells outside of it will become nodata).